# How to compare an input string with a declared string for some further conditional actions

Tags: arduino-uno

I need to take an input in a string and check if it matches a preset string.

I tried to take the input and match it with the declared string namely, the `String yes` with my input string `String cmd`.
But even with matching input, it is running the `else` condition.
Here's my code.

```
# define LED1 12
String cmd;
String yes=String("YES");    

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);

}    

void loop()
{
  while(Serial.available())
  {
    cmd=Serial.readString(); 
    if(cmd.equals(yes)) //checking equality of my input string with the predefined string.
    {
      //code to do something with the LED
    }
    else
    {
      //some error message
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "\r\n" in your input string. Try this

```
String yes=String("YES\r\n");
```

and if possible avoid the String altogether and follow this [awesome tutoral](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=396450)